# Can you hook/intercept ShellExecute?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am writing an addon for an application that internally calls ShellExecute to open URLs in the default browser.
I want to intercept and re-route this call to my addon to handle it there, instead of opening the browser.

Setting the Registry keys would be one option, but this would affect the user when multi-tasking and I may not be able to reset the key if the application crashes or doesn't shut down properly.

So is there anyway to intercept this call so I can handle it myself?

I already looked at the Registry keys for the default browser.

There was also a similar question to this mentioning SetWindowsHookEx, but that has no relation to ShellExecute as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That is not relevant to the question. I have a C++ library running inside of an application. I want to hook ShellExecute in some way to intercept browser calls. I have WndProc, otherwise I don't interface with the application unless I hook something.

Comment: maybe SetWinEventHook can help you.

Comment: There's still the concept of `IShellExecuteHook` (defined in Windows SDK %ProgramFiles%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\ShlObj_core.h) but it's global and needs admin right to be configured obviously. You must add a your CLSID as a value in `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellExecuteHooks` key and enable POLID_EnableShellExecuteHooks on recent Windows https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/c/ixdOX1--IKk

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171220-00/?p=97615 Does this help?

Comment: No, @Torrecto-MSFT, this doesn't help. It explains how to control the program being launched as the caller of `ShellExecute()`. The question is asking about a program that isn't.